# Execute the code once the file transfer is complete in python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, csv, python-watchdog

I have two machines: machine-A and machine-B. I am transferring (SFTP) a .csv file (for example: test.csv of size 2GB) from machine-A to machine-B. I have a python script (shown below) that runs for 24x7 on machine-B. This script monitors the current folder and if it sees a .csv file, it sends the data to another machine with MySQL on it (see in the code below if interested). But, I only want this python script to do its job ONLY after test.csv is completely transfered from machine-A to machine-B. I found a post on stackoverflow but couldn't quite use it. Any idea?

Python script:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import sys
import string
import traceback
import time  
from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler 

if not os.path.exists('Archive'):
    os.mkdir("Archive")
if not os.path.exists('Failed'):
    os.mkdir("Failed")

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.csv"]

    def process(self, event):
        """
        event.event_type 
            'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'
        event.is_directory
            True | False
        event.src_path
            path/to/observed/file
        """

        # Open database connection
        db = MySQLdb.connect (host="1.2.3.4",port=3333,user="userAdmin",\
                              passwd="passAdmin",db="tableAdmin",local_infile=1)
        cursor=db.cursor()

        #Query under testing
        sql = open('test.sql','r').read()

        # the file will be processed there
        print 'Processing .csv file '+event.src_path+' as it is '+event.event_type
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql.format(event.src_path))
            db.commit()
            print 'Executed and Commited the QUERY on .csv file '+event.src_path
            os.rename(event.src_path,(event.src_path).split('/')[0]+'/Archive/'+(event.src_path).split('/')[1]+'.archive')
        except:
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            os.rename(event.src_path,(event.src_path).split('/')[0]+'/Failed/'+(event.src_path).split('/')[1]+'.fail-db')
            print 'ERROR-See Traceback message below'
            traceback.print_exc()
            db.rollback()   

        db.close()
        print "Disconnected from the MySQL server"
        print '-----------#*#*#*-----------#*#*#*-----------'

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path='.')
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Comment: Maybe consider using `rsync` instead, as it might be better suited for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could transfer another (zero-byte) file after the CSV is transferred, and watch for that instead. Your script could delete it when it’s finished.

At the moment it’s not really possible for your script to know when the transfer is complete, because it doesn’t know how big the file is meant to be. Some kind of other trigger from machine A is going to be necessary.

You could also run this code on machine A instead, connecting to MySQL on machine B, removing the need for the SFTP transfer. (If MySQL communication is possible and secure between them.)

Comment: This is one of the possibilities I have on paper but that would require me to modify whatever the script (on machine-A) is sending the file from machine-A to machine-B. I am trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: See updated answer explaining why you can’t know when the transfer is finished from machine B without some other trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can override few methods of MyHandler class, which can solve your issue.

1) `on_created()`
It gets triggered when ever new file is created (complete transferred) in given directory, which in turn invokes process function to process the file.

This method works for me, I am using bt-sync.

2) `on_moved()`
It gets triggered when ever new file is **rsynced**, which inturn invokes process function to process the file.

You can modify your code to override `on_created` method:-

```
class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.csv"]
    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print "file modified " + event.src_path
        self.process(event)
    def on_moved(self, event):
        print "file moved" + event.src_path
        self.process(event)
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print "file deleted" + event.src_path
        self.process(event)
    def process(self, event):
        ....
```

For more details http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html